# POSTMAN- Generate Request body dynamically using Data Files to pass values for certain fields

Tags: postman, web-api-testing, postman-pre-request-script

How can I generate this payload automatically in postman. Please see the structure below.

I am only changing Account Number / Account Name in the payload. If I have add 200 accounts for a customer ID I would have to insert 200 separate structures in the array. Is there a better way to maintain and generate the payload on the fly as I know that only 2 fields are changing and I could pass these as variables.
I tried the Collection Runner but I am unable to send these as one request.

FYI - For another corporate it would be 100 or 50 or 500, I wish to use the same payload for any request.

### FYI-  need to pass all these accounts in one request is because any second request its treated as a modify by the server.

```
{
  "context": {
    "EID": "ACC_123",
    "eventTime": "2018-01-02T00:00:00.000Z",
    "Eaction": "INIT"
  },
"payload": [
{
"accountNumber": "12345",
"accountName": "abcd",
"accountAliasName": "",
"customerId": "150740000",
"ccy": "THB",
"accountStatus": "A",
"branch": "001",
"bankCode":"0001"
},
{
"accountNumber": "123456",
"accountName": "abcde",
"accountAliasName": "",
"customerId": "150740001",
"ccy": "THB",
"accountStatus": "A",
"branch": "001",
"bankCode":"0001"
}
]
```

---

Updated-

Pre-req:

```
payloadarr.push(
        {
        "accountNumber": Account_Number ,
        "accountName": Account_Name,
...
"context": {
    "eventID": "TEST_JSL_0120191",
    "eventTime": "2018-01-02T00:00:00.000Z",
    "action": "INITIATE"
                },
  "payload": [payloadarr]
```

Body:

```
{{AccountActivation_Payload}}
...
```

Request passed:

```
{"context":{"eventID":"TEST_JSL_0120191","eventTime":"2018-01-02T00:00:00.000Z","action":"INITIATE"},"payload":[[]]}
```

Expectation:
payload should have the appended values

```
{"context":{"eventID":"TEST_JSL_0120191","eventTime":"2018-01-02T00:00:00.000Z","action":"INITIATE"},"payload":[{
    "accountNumber": "12345",
    "accountName": "abcd",
    "accountAliasName": "",
    "customerId": "150740000",
    "ccy": "THB",
    "accountStatus": "A",
    "branch": "001",
    "bankCode":"0001"
    },]}
```

Comment: in Pre-req write `"payload": payloadarr` and in Body are you writing `payloadarr.push(...` ?

Comment: No, it was a copy paste issue.Updated it
I realize my code is failing because I am using data variables in pre-request screen.

Answer (score 0):

you can create the following `Pre-request Script`

```
var requestBody = {
  "context": {
    "EID": "ACC_123",
    "eventTime": "2018-01-02T00:00:00.000Z",
    "Eaction": "INIT"
  },
  "payload": []
};

for (var i = 0; i < 200; i++) {
  requestBody.payload.push({
    "accountNumber": 12345 + i,
    "accountName": "abcd" + i,
    "accountAliasName": "",
    "customerId": "150740000",
    "ccy": "THB",
    "accountStatus": "A",
    "branch": "001",
    "bankCode": "0001"
  });
}

postman.setEnvironmentVariable('requestBody', JSON.stringify(requestBody));
```

and it set Environment Variable `requestBody` then you can call it in the request body using `{{requestBody}}`

Comment: The payload is going empty                 {"context":{"eventID":"TEST_JSL_0120191","eventTime":"2018-01-02T00:00:00.000Z","action":"INITIATE"},"payload":[[]]}     .

Comment: please add screenshot how you define the `Body`

Comment: I have actually replaced the loop variable with datafield variables  
---------------------------

 var Account_Number = pm.iterationData.get("Account_Number")

"accountNumber": Account_Number ,
  "accountName": Account_Name,
  "accountAliasName": "ABC",
  "customerId": Customer_ID,
  "bankEntityId":"THAILAND",

postman.setEnvironmentVariable('AccountActivation_Payload', JSON.stringify(Tmprequest));


BODY:
{{AccountActivation_Payload}}

Comment: This is also part of  Pre-request script

for (var i=0;i>=3;i++)
{
var Account_Number = pm.iterationData.get("Account_Number");
var Account_Name = pm.iterationData.get("Account_Name");

Comment: please post the code in your question, it less readable in comment

Comment: I realize my code is failing because I am using data variables in  pre-request screen. that is why the payload code is coming blank. Is there an alternative?

Comment: When I changed the File format to JSON, it worked fine. Any reason why the code did not pick values when it was a a CSV file?